# Irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Why is $X^2-3$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ ?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of irreducible? What part of it do you not understand which makes this unclear to you?

Comment: I think I have just to show that the polynomial doesn't have a root on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ because it is of degree 2.

Comment: You have more tags than question. Where did you find this result? What do you know about irreducible polynomials? Please read the advice [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is right: if $X^2-3$ is reducible, then $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ and you have
$$
\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]
$$
Can you apply the dimension formula?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I would say $ [\mathbb{Q} : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]] * [\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3} ]] = [\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2} : \mathbb{Q}]$. Then we have $2*[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]] : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3} ] = 2$ so $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3} ]] = 1$. And it means $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ ?

Comment: @user503143 You should know that $[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}:\mathbb{Q}]=3$.

Comment: @user503143 You have $3=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})]\cdot2$. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh yes sorry... then we woud have $ [\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] : \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] ] = 3/2$, which is absurd ?

Comment: @user503143 Degrees of extensions are integers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was a little bit lost...